# Item assignment for flattened array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am translating a FEM-DG solver, and to apply boundary conditions, I must apply the following code:

`dEz.T.flatten()[mapB] = 2*Ez.T.flatten()[vmapB]`

where both `dEz` and `Ez` are of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. However, after, I check with the assignment with the assertion,
`assert np.all(dEz.T.flatten()[mapB] == 2*Ez.T.flatten()[vmapB])`

which ultimatly fails.

I admit, the flattening and the transpose seems long-winded, but I am translating code from Matlab where the assignment is a little more straightforward, but perhaps I am missing something.

Here is a small example, which shows my problem:

``

```
import numpy as np;
E = np.linspace(1, 20, 20).reshape((4, 5));
V = E + 5;
E.T.flatten()[[0, 1, 2]] = V.T.flatten()[[7, 10, 1]];
assert np.all(E.T.flatten()[[0, 1, 2]] == V.T.flatten()[[7, 10, 1]])
```

``

Thank you in advance for helping me resolve this issue.

Comment: `flattened` makes a copy.  `ravel` does not, except here it follows `T`.  The order of elements in the mask and RHS need to be considered which figuring out a substitute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [ndarray.flat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html), which returns a flatten iterator on the array:

An example:

```
v = np.ones((3,3))
v.flat[[3,4,5]] = [0,0,0]
print(v)

[[1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

And here is the corrected version of your code:

```
import numpy as np;
E = np.linspace(1, 20, 20).reshape((4, 5));
V = E + 5;
E.T.flat[[0, 1, 2]] = V.T.flatten()[[7, 10, 1]];
assert np.all(E.T.flatten()[[0, 1, 2]] == V.T.flatten()[[7, 10, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning values to `flattened numpy arrays` can be hard, because the function `flatten()` explicitly returns a copy of the initial array, whereas `ravel()` has an ambiguous documentation stating that arrays are only copied when "needed"(??).

I think the best approach is to take a step back, and define a simple loop calling a two-liner function, which returns the original position in the 2D array `[m,n]` for any element `i` in the posterior `flattened-array`:

```
# A) Auxiliary function: index_flat
#      Returns the equivalent A[m,n] coordinates for any flattened-array index (i)'

def index_flat(A,i):
    c = A.shape[1]
    return i//c, i%c

# B) Initialization
import numpy as np;

E = np.linspace(1, 20, 20).reshape((4, 5));
V = E + 5;

# C) Classic Loop
inds_ET = [0,  1, 2]
inds_VT = [7, 10, 1]

for i,j in zip(inds_ET,inds_VT):
    i2       =  index_flat(E.T,i)
    j2       =  index_flat(V.T,j)
    E.T[i2]  =  V.T[j2]

# D) Assertion
assert np.all(E.T.flatten()[[0, 1, 2]] == V.T.flatten()[[7, 10, 1]])
```

PS. The answer of @MarcoP is really good. I was not aware of the existence of the `flat` method as an iterator. Nice to know.